# Can I wire the ouput and Vcc of an electret condenser microphone amplifier and get the same signal out?

Tags: amplifier, audio, microphone, condenser-microphone

So I am using MAX9812 amplifier to build a microphone module, but from the pic you can see it requires 3 wires, vcc, ground and output.
[image: max9812 application scheme]

I was thinking to wire Vcc with output to get rid of one wire, making it a 2 wire system, is this possible without losing the amplification?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Electric condenser microphones need about 1.5 volts of 'phantom' power, that is it shares the same wire as that which carries the very weak mic output. These mics have an FET in them for impedance matching, thus the need for a few volts.

Comment: I know the need for bias voltage for ecm, but that's not my question. My question is essentially asking is it possible to wire Vcc and OUT (in the picture)  together and maybe a still somehow get the amplified microphone signal on this combined wire.

Comment: Answer:   NO . If you want a 2 wire mic  , use a typ. FET buffered electret mic alone

Comment: Don't try to re-invent the wheel. This is as basic as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

> I was thinking to wire Vcc with output to get rid of one wire, making
>   it a 2 wire system, is this possible without losing the amplification?

[image]

It's called phantom powering and works fine for balanced stage microphones and will work OK for short runs of cable connected to an unbalanced microphone but be aware that noise will eventually become a nuisance because the unbalanced microphone.

Answer (score 1):

Two-wire operation is a compromise for low-powered signal sources.  The output of an electret mic is matched well to that application regarding currents and signal levels and impedance and SNR ratio.  A component like the MAX9812 is intended for use in a larger circuit such as a laptop.  Its signal and power levels and impedance are higher than sensibly transferred mixed up across NF lines.

While you can find 3-wire to 2-wire circuits (essentially a mixture of resistors and capacitors for separating DC and NF AC) for the sake of using MEMS microphones in 2-wire circuits, those tend to have quite lower operating current.  You can adapt such circuits for larger currents, of course.

But the MAX9812 adds 20dB of amplification on top of the comparatively high gain of a 2-wire electret microphone, and those are already prone to clipping at large signal levels without any amplification.

So it's hard to see what you want to achieve.  You'll likely want a powering circuit of your own design, and then there is little point in not packing the the MAX9812 in the same place you are packing your powering circuit.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use one wire for both power and signal you need a way to combine them at one end and separate them at the other without one interfering with the other.

In some cases this can be done with resistors and capacitors, but the current will be limited. In other cases you need to use inductors and capacitors.

For example you can use inductors to block AC and pass DC, and capacitors to pass AC and block DC like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbhALA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is often used at RF frequencies but at audio frequencies the inductances needed can become large. You can replace them with resistors in some situations but you need to be able to supply the correct voltage and enough current to the device being powered. This would generally mean using a higher source voltage and regulating it down at the destination. In either case you will probably need bypassing for the power, such as a capacitor at the Vcc/Gnd of the device being powered.

Comment: I hope this is useful to someone, because I just realized I was answering a 4 year old question.